# help mongrel wont start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I have decided to switch from Restful authentication to authlogic.. so what I did was delete every file and folder that got installed when I downloaded the plugin.. now when I try to "ruby script/server" I get

> script/server
>   => Booting Mongrel
>   => Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
>   /Users/nachof/Sites/unet/config/initializers/production.rb:5:
>   undefined local variable or method
>   `config' for main:Object (NameError)
>     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in`
>   load_without_new_constant_marking'
>     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`
>   new_constants_in'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:622:in`
>   load_application_initializers'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:621:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:621:in`
>   load_application_initializers'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:176:in
>   `process'      ... 8 levels...    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:84
>     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'     from script/server:3
>   Macintosh:unet nachof$

Help please

Comment: For future reference you can use script/plugin remove _<plugin_name>_

Answer (score 0):

Check `environment.rb` as you have a typo in your `config.gem` lines I believe.

Comment: thanks but doesnt seem to be it as the only line thats not commented is
config.time_zone = 'UTC'